# Android: process lifecycle and database access

Tags: android, database, lifecycle

Under the following assumptions:

1. Every blocking action (including I/O, including db access) must occur outside the UI thread.
2. When no activity or service is active, then the associated process is eligible to be killed in priority ([empty process](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)).

How do you save something in database (sqlite) on leaving an activity?

Indeed, in `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onBackPressed()`, you must not write to database (I/O in UI thread). So you can create a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`, but in that case, it is possible that no activity or service will be active during `AsyncTask` execution, so the process will be considered "inactive", and will be killed in priority.

For a very long operation, you could create a service, but you won't do that only for saving state into database.

What do you think?

Comment: Why you "won't do that only for saving state into database"?

Comment: Imagine you want to edit a profile and save it to database on leaving the activity: I think it would be overkill to use a service, don't you?

Comment: A counter question: If you save it when you leave the activity - why don't you persist any change immediately as soon as the user has changed a field? Or offer a dedicated save button that will (a) block and save and b) leave the activity afterwards?